# Can you "unpublish" a page in Ektron without scheduling it to expire?

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

I have some pages in an Ektron based website and I would like to change their status from "Approved (Published)" to an unpublished status and prevent the page from displaying in navigation, etc.

I have tried to edit the properties of the page and can find no means of changing the status of the page. Google searches have suggested to schedule the page to expire with a date in the past to immediately archive the page, but that seems more like a workaround than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an "unpublish" button, and from memory, setting the expire date to the past is the Ektron approved method of doing this.

(Checking out a piece of content will still leave the previous version live)

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is correct, there is no unpublish facility which is a glaring omission.

Setting expire to the past is a bit of a faff. The other option you have is to temporarily remove the page from the taxonomy via the 'category' tab in page edit mode.

Cheers
Ed

Answer (score 1):

You can set the permissions to `"The content in this folder is private and can only be viewed by authorized users and members"` and this will hide your page/content from the public.